# Ruby delegation/proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, delegates, ruby-1.9.2

Given the following code:

```
class ArrayProxy < BasicObject
  def initialize
    @array = []
  end

  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end

  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    @array = @array.send(*args, &block)
  end

  def self.method_missing(*args, &block)
    new.send(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

Why is the call to 'foo' being delegated to the array?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :018 > ArrayProxy.new << 1
 => [1] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :019 > ArrayProxy << 1
 => [1] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :020 > ArrayProxy.new.foo
foo
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :021 > ArrayProxy.foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for []:Array
```

Comment: Try `__send__` in your code. That might do it.

Comment: That did do it, from documentation 'You can use __send__ if the name send clashes with an existing method in obj.' But 'foo' isn't a method in Object? Could someone clarify for the accepted answer?

Comment: Btw, why do you re-assign `@array` inside `method_missing`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh noted in the comment you should use `__send__` method in that case, as `BasicObject` doesn't define instance method `send`:

```
Object.instance_methods.grep /send/
# => [:send, :public_send, :__send__] 

BasicObject.instance_methods.grep /send/
# => [:__send__]
```

That can be proven by docs for [`BasicObject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html) as well.

Absence of `send` instance method in `BasicObect` class results into following chain of calls:

```
# initial call
ArrayProxy.foo

# there's no class method 'foo', so we go to class 'method_missing' method
ArrayProxy.method_missing :foo

# inside class 'method_missing' we delegate call to new instance using 'send'
ArrayProxy.new.send :foo

# there is no instance method 'send' in ArrayProxy class (and its parent class
# BasicObject) so instance 'method_missing' is called
ArrayProxy.new.method_missing :send, :foo

# instance 'method_missing' delegates call of 'send' method to @array
@array.send :send, :foo

# that is unfolded into regular call of 'send' on @array object
@array.send :foo

# and finally 'foo' is called for @array object
@array.foo
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for []:Array
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would make more sense to use a Ruby standard library tool, instead of rolling your own?

[Delegator class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html). (I pointed to the 1.9.3 docs, but the class exists in 1.8.x also).

Comment: Not necessarily. If you use `Delegator` or subclass it, methods such as `class` will *not* be delegated. `BasicObject`'s minimal set of methods lets you create an object that can "stand-in" for the original object in more scenarios than `Delegator` allows.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for `method_missing` is `method_sym, *args, &block`.

<del>I think it is being sent to the array as you are calling `new` in the class level `method_missing` declaration (which instantiates a new ArrayProxy) and calling send on the return value.</del>

I'm slightly confused as to why you are setting the `@array` equal to the return value of `@array.send(*args, &block)` in the instance level declaration of `method_missing`.

**Edit:** this is rather odd behaviour. Would expect sending `:foo` to an instance of `ArrayProxy` to print foo rather than delegating the call to its `@array` through `method_missing`.